# Implement a global listener for Selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, junit5

I use this code to click on a series of dialog windows with unique button ID. It was working fine till now because the order was strict:

```
clickConfirmWindow(driver, SURVEY_EXIT_BUTTON_ID_LOCATOR, "Survey exit window");

... and many mode windows with unique ID with random order

protected void clickConfirmWindow(WebDriver driver, String elementId, String name) {
        // Check if warning window is displayed using button ID
        System.out.println("Searching " + name + " using " + elementId);
        if (isClickable(driver, elementId, 1)) {
            System.out.println("Found " + name + " using " + elementId);
            driver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).click();
        }
    }

protected void clickConfirmWindow(WebDriver driver, String elementId, String name) {
        // Check if warning window is displayed using button ID
        System.out.println("Searching " + name + " using " + elementId);
        if (isClickable(driver, elementId, 1)) {
            System.out.println("Found " + name + " using " + elementId);
            driver.findElement(By.id(elementId)).click();
        }
    }

private Boolean isClickable(WebDriver driver, String elementId, int timeOut) {
        try {
            new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(elementId)));
            return true;
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But now the order of the windows is random. Is it possible to implement some kind of global listener which listens for web element ID thru out the entire application and clicks it if it's present?

Comment: there is a webdriver event listener... (and apparently a new version of it): https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html  (Not sure how well supported it is...)  You could also just create a superclass (abstract class) for your wrappers there and have your wrappers extend it.

Comment: could you please share the HTML code of the confirm window as well? what if you can handle all the confirmation boxed using only one method. I am thinking of making the button locator independent of id [common for all confirmation window].

Answer (score 1):

Searching if the element exists should help you

```
WebElement elementName = driver.findElement(By.id("idElement")); 

if(elementName != null){
   //Loaded Element 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your specific situation but in vba I would write an if statement to see if it was true,

If driver.findelementsbyid("your Id").count > 0 then
driver.findelementbyid("your Id").click
Else
End if